# How to split a PDF to multiple overlapping pages with cpdf?

Tags: pdf, crop, pdf-cropping

I am trying to use [`cpdf`](https://www.coherentpdf.com) to split single-page PDFs of various page height in to PDFs with multiple pages of a fixed A4 page size with some overlap for the page end of a page to the begin of the next page.

I tried to get at least a first page with

cpdf -mediabox a4portrait mypdf.pdf -o out.pdf

but this gives me the error '*Bad rectangle specification a4portrait : Pdf.PDFError("Bad rectangle specification a4portrait")*'

Also I have to find out the aspect ratio of `mypdf.pdf` to determine how many pages I have to create, but I coudl not find any way to do this with `cpdf`. -- Do I need another command for this?

Answer (score 1):

A rectangle is specified by four numbers. "a4portrait" will expand to two numbers. So that's why you can't use it there.

You could therefore do `cpdf -mediabox "0 0 a4portrait" in.pdf -o out.pdf`.

For your task, I would:

1. Use `-page-info` to find the height of your original page
2. Calculate the coordinates for each output page, including the overlap you want
3. Run `-mediabox` on each one, providing the four numbers (min x, min y, width, height).

Comment: Thanks @johnwhitington! That's GREAT help. I will try it out.