# How to split a long single page PDF in multiple pages?

Tags: pdf

I've a PDF file made by a long single page probably it was realized by a tablet.

How can I split it in multiple pages? I want to keep the horizontal size.

**Attention**: The goal is not to split a PDF file containing more than one page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way I found to do that is to **Print to PDF** and use ***Adobe Acrobat Reader***'s **Poster** printing options.

1. Open file in Adobe Acrobat Reader
2. Choose **Print** from the menu (or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)
3. For the *Printer* select **Microsoft Print to PDF**
4. For *Page Sizing & Handling* select **Poster**
5. Depending on the current width of the file, you may need to play around with the *Tile Scale* so that the width is a single page of the size you want

[image]

Comment: Are there any similar-but-native options for users unwilling to install third-party software? For example, for Windows users, would Microsoft's "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer driver suffice? Or, for macOS, "Save as PDF" (possibly with some extra work)?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible natively. (BTW, how do you view PDFs in the first place - to be able to print them - natively?)

Comment: Edge can display PDFs. Apple's Safari too.

Comment: ...which I suppose count as native as you don't get the OS without them.

Comment: *Edge runs both types of Acrobat Reader* oh noes, my faith in MS has just gone(!). I'll carry on with... is there no route untainted by Adobe nowadays?

Comment: @KJ I guess we have to hope that Adobe is the least leaky of the PDF software vendors in that case. LOL.

Answer (score 3):

The PDF function you require is usually termed splitting into "Poster" tiles.

It can often be done in Acrobat Printing. See the answer by [yisroel-tech](https://superuser.com/a/1836252/1769247). But it is best to check the settings for output page size and advisable to add a reasonable overlap, since lines of text or section headings may need to avoid splitting badly. The split overlap is often "tidied-up" in a GUI editor to avoid duplication. A major downside with this approach is it can produce a large white space top of first page and bottom of last.

[image]

However several command line tools offer different methods of doing similar, very easily, by say a matrix of `1x3` where 1 is current width and 3 is the number of page outputs in the result.

To give a more accurate answer will depend on the source and task. Thus desirable you link to a copy for testing methods or at least provide clues as to internal PDF dimensions and desired page sizes for emulating similar result.

Simplest (one.exe) example. One advantage is it duplicates a split line of text (minimising edits to one page or the other) and the equal height pages can be later centred into a common fixed layout.

MuPDF `Mutool Poster -x 1 -y 3 in.pdf out.pdf`

```
mutool poster [options] input.pdf [output.pdf]
        -p -    password
        -x      x decimation factor
        -y      y decimation factor
        -r      split right-to-left
```

For a [coherent cpdf](https://www.coherentpdf.com/) answer (many variants) [see this](https://superuser.com/a/1835593/1769247).

```
cpdf -mediabox "0 0 a4portrait" in.pdf -o out.pdf
```

More complex cases may need [pdfcpu](https://pdfcpu.io/) or other trim related command line (MuTool has that, unsure about cpdf?):

```
pdfcpu trim -pages 1-4 "$file" "trimmed/$file" || ret="$?"
```

One of the more complex cases I ever saw (36 1/4 pages) was answered by a double approach. First remove the surplus page header, then split the desired remaining page into 36 equal pages.

```
cpdf -cropbox "11.525pt 24pt 185 8164" T6.pdf -o tmp.pdf
mutool poster -x 1 -y 36 "tmp.PDF" "out.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are tools for splitting a PDF file vertically.
I have only found tools which do that for half pages, meaning convert
each page into two, but running the tool again can consecutively split
it to 4, 8 etc pages.

A free tool is
[PDF24 Tools](https://tools.pdf24.org/en/), which is also available
as an online tool at
[Split PDF](https://tools.pdf24.org/en/split-pdf#s=1711124433038).

Note that splitting the page vertically will not generate new page
headers or footers. These will be included in the split pages
whichever page they happen to fall into.

Comment: Isn't that tool to split files off existing multi-page PDF files?

Comment: @YisroelTech: It generates one PDF file that includes all the half-pages consecutively.

Comment: Doesn't seem to me like it. Try to split this file to 4 pages https://1drv.ms/b/s!Ao8EzDmtlA0Jln0q5pyPJySQ0coV?e=FslcKC

Comment: @YisroelTech: Worked for me. Did you set the Mode to "Halve pages" and saved at each step?

Comment:  that works indeed. I didn't realize I need to switch the Mode